# Identifying what's wrong with my code

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

What i'm trying to do is to create a new column that will tell me each country's population in 2015.

The columns of the DF are:

```
['id', 'code', 'name', 'area', 'area_land', 'area_water', 'population',
   'population_growth', 'birth_rate', 'death_rate', 'migration_rate',
   'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

Here it is guys:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import math

con = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Python34\factbook.db')
facts = pd.read_sql_query('select * from facts;', con)
facts.dropna()
facts = facts[facts['area_land']!=0][:]
facts = facts[facts['population']!=0][:]

def pop_in_50(name):
    pop=facts[facts['name']==name]['population']
    prec = facts[facts['name']==name]['population_growth']
    new_pop = pop*math.e**(35*(prec/100))
    return new_pop

facts['pop_in_2050'] = facts['name'].apply(pop_in_50)
```

It gives the following errror:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 259, placement implies 1

Comment: On which line is this failing?

Comment: `facts.dropna(inplace=True)`

Comment: while this might be another problem with my code, it does not solve the error. I stil get: " Wrong number of items passed 215, placement implies 1 "

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_pop = pop.values*math.e**(35*(prec.values/100))
```